# Angular, angularfire - get value in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

I'm making web app and i have a problem with getting values from input text. How to get them from the inputs?

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'firebase']);

app.controller("AuthCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
   var ref = firebase.database().ref();
   $scope.data = $firebaseObject(ref);
});

app.controller("AuthCtrl", ["$scope", "$firebaseAuth", 
function($scope, $firebaseAuth) {
  $scope.login = function($scope) {
    var login = '';
    var pass = '';

    $scope.authObj = $firebaseAuth();
    $scope.authObj.$signInWithEmailAndPassword(login, pass)
    .then(function(firebaseUser) {
        console.log("Signed in as:", firebaseUser.uid);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
   });
  }
 }
]);
```

THE SOLUTION:
Wrong controller used.
From AuthCtrl to loginCtrl everything works!
Everything 'cause i'm using ngRoute.

```
app.controller("logintCtrl", ["$scope", "$firebaseAuth", 
function($scope, $firebaseAuth) {
   $scope.login = function($scope) {
     var login = '';
     var pass = '';

    $scope.authObj = $firebaseAuth();
    $scope.authObj.$signInWithEmailAndPassword(login, pass)
    .then(function(firebaseUser) {
       console.log("Signed in as:", firebaseUser.uid);
    }).catch(function(error) {
       console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
    });
   }
 }
]);
```

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms (Simple Form)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#simple-form). *The [ngModel directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) provides the two-way data-binding by synchronizing the model to the view, as well as view to the model.*

Comment: Angular 1.6.3, Firebase 3.8.0, Angularefire 2.3.0

Comment: I'm following this: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#signing-users-in

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the HTML code but I will assume let say you have a form in this format

```
<form name="myForm">
<input type="login" ng-model="myForm.login">
<input type="password" ng-model="myForm.pass">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

now your js should

> Take note of the **form name**. You should also note that Firebase only accept **email** and other string for authentication. Which means first string must be email format

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'firebase']);

app.controller("AuthCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
   var ref = firebase.database().ref();
   $scope.data = $firebaseObject(ref);
});

app.controller("AuthCtrl", ["$scope", "$firebaseAuth", 
function($scope, $firebaseAuth) {
  $scope.login = function($scope.myForm) {
    var login = $scope.myForm.login;
    var pass = $scope.myForm.pass;



    $scope.authObj = $firebaseAuth();
    $scope.authObj.$signInWithEmailAndPassword(login, pass)
    .then(function(firebaseUser) {
        console.log("Signed in as:", firebaseUser.uid);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
   });
  }
 }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `$scope` as the argument name in the `$scope.login` function:

```
app.controller("AuthCtrl", ["$scope", "$firebaseAuth", 
function($scope, $firebaseAuth) {
  //ERRONEOUS
  //$scope.login = function($scope) {
  //INSTEAD
  $scope.login = function() {
    var login = 'user@example.com';
    var pass = '12345';

    $scope.authObj = $firebaseAuth();
    $scope.authObj.$signInWithEmailAndPassword(login, pass)
    .then(function(firebaseUser) {
        console.log("Signed in as:", firebaseUser.uid);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
   });
  }
 }
]);
```

By using `$scope` as the first parameter of the `$scope.login`, it hides the `$scope` object reference injected in the controller construction function.